# Reproducible results with parallel_for and random numbers possible?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, random, parallel-processing, random-seed

I have code which involves some heavy computations so I use the parallel_for loop in Visual Studio C++. This works fine and the code runs much faster in comparison with a normal for loop.

My problem is that I want reproducible results but the computations involve random numbers. I can use a fixed seed but this does seem to work when using a parallel_for loop.

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <ppl.h>

#define USE_PAR 1

std::mutex m;
double x_min = 1.0e300;

double draw()
{
    int seed = 1;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> d(-1.0, 1.0);
    static std::mt19937 mt(seed);
    return d(mt);
}

void expensive_function()
{
    double x;
    for (volatile int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
        x = draw();
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    if (x < x_min)
        x_min = x;
}

void test()
{
#if USE_PAR
    concurrency::parallel_for(size_t(0), size_t(10), [&](size_t i) { expensive_function(); });
#else
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { expensive_function(); }
#endif
    std::cout << x_min << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) test();
}
```

When I use a normal for loop instead of parallel_for (`USE_PAR = 0`), I reproducibly get the same output every time I run the program:

```
-0.935609
-0.952062
-0.952062
-0.952062
-0.952062
-0.952062
-0.988225
-0.988225
-0.988225
-0.99249
```

But with the parallel_for loop (`USE_PAR = 1`), I get a different result everytime. For example the first time:

```
-0.733511
-0.733511
-0.855412
-0.855412
-0.93122
-0.93122
-0.93122
-0.987444
-0.987444
-0.987444
```

And then the second time:

```
-0.90946
-0.997749
-0.997749
-0.997749
-0.997749
-0.997749
-0.997749
-0.997749
-0.997749
-0.997749
```

Is it possible to have both? Good performance with parallel_for and reproducible results even if random numbers are used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because you have undefined behavior. You call the `static` random number generator from multiple threads at once.

Make it `thread_local` (it also becomes `static` when you do):

```
thread_local std::mt19937 mt(seed);
```

Note: I don't know the `<ppl.h>` library, but making a variable `volatile` is pointless as long as the variable is under the program's control (that is, not connected to some external hardware that may change it). Drop the `volatile int i` and make it `int i`.

Comment: This will result in all threads using the same sequence of random numbers, because they all use the same seed value.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Exactly. That's what OP wanted. Reproducible results.

Comment: But having every thread use the same random sequence seems counter to the use of threads, since all of the threads would do the same work with the same numbers. May as well stick with one thread then and save yourself from all that duplicated effort.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm OP seems to be experimenting. The whole loop thing to call `draw` a 1000 times is also just there to make it take time and OP wants to see the effect of doing costly calculations in parallel if I understand it correctly.